# What is the reason for (gas_used) change using the function and parameters?

Tags: ether, gas, dapps

I am using a Dapp connected with MetaMask and smart contract. I try to conduct a function named addUser(id, name), I enter two users, one with `addUser(12, Jack)`, while the second with `addUser(43, Alex)`, the (gas used) was different, which surprised me,  why gas used change although both users have the same parameters and the same number of digits? I couldn't find a good explanation for this! I know the gas used calculated depends on the complexity of the function or transaction. Can someone help me to understand this?

thanks a lot.